# Free -m and free -k display same quantities

Tags: linux, memory, centos

When running the commands `free -m` and `free -k`, they display the same quantity of memory. Furthermore, `free --mega` and `free --kilo` display the expected quantities (the correct ones).

What might be the root cause of this problem and how I could I fix this?

Comment: First thing I'd do is identify the source for `free` from which your binary is compiled, recompile it to make sure, and then check the source if there isn't a copy&paste bug. If yes, submit a patch, unless it's already fixed in the newest version.